# Función que devuelva un array con los numeros menores que n en primer lugar y luego ceros. Java

Tags: java

Tengo actualmente esta función

```
public static int[] menoresQueN(int[] array, int n){
    int [] res = new int[array.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i] < n){
        res[i]=array[i];
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
```

Pero cuando le paso el siguiente array, array={1,3,4,5,6,2,1} y n = 3
Me devuelve --> {1,0,0,0,0,0,2,1} pero me debería devolver {1,2,1,0,0,0,0,0}

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te está ocurriendo es que estás insertando cada número que cumple con la condición en el lugar del elemento de la tabla original. Es decir, que si el elemento `array[i] < n`, insertas dicho elemento en la posición `i` de la array `res`. Es por ello que te queda ese orden. Cada elemento está en su sitio original, y el resto son ceros, que es como se inicalizan los arrays de tipos enteros por defecto en Java.

Para solucionarlo, puedes llevar un índice paralelo (un contador), que comience en 0 y se actualice sólo cuando se cumpla la condición `array[i] < n`. Entonces, se sumará 1 al índice, para que la próxima vez que se cumpla la condición, el valor se inserte seguido del anterior.

Aquí la función y un ejemplo de llamada desde main:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array={1,3,4,5,6,2,1};
        int[] nArray = menoresQueN(array, 3);
        for (int i = 0; i < nArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(nArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    public static int[] menoresQueN(int[] array, int n){
        int j = 0;
        int[] res = new int[array.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] < n){
                 res[j]=array[i];
                 j += 1;
            }
        }
       return res;
    }
```

Debería devolverte `1 2 1 0 0 0 0`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!